# Customizing visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I open a .c file in visual studio code, I always needed to copy and paste all the header files and some of my predefined macros, But is there any way to customize visual studio code so that they are automatically written when I open a .c file in visual studio code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vscode  task or your own plugin.
In this case I think creating your own snipet will help you:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets